# A sentence's meaning

Tags: verbs

About the sentence

> 北海道では雪が降っています。

Does it mean:

1. It is snowing in Hokkaido, or
2. It is still going to be snowing in Hokkaido?

Comment: The first option is a straight-forward translation. How did you come up with the second option?

Comment: sai, are you familiar with the ていく construction? e.g., 降っている vs 降っていく?

Comment: I was reading a book on Japanese grammar written in Chinese. The book translates the sentence into 北海道仍持續降雪, and I translated this into (2).

Comment: Yes I have learned about 降っていく, but do not quite understand its meaning.

Comment: 「sai」って「犀」のことなん？

Comment: @sai Don't trust translations -too- much - you risk bringing things over from the gloss language.

Comment: @Sjiveru Okay I think I will try to not.

Comment: @istrasci まあ、「犀」は「sai」の一つだけの可能性だよね。

Comment: @sai We rarely say 雪が降っていく. Does the sentence 2 mean "it will keep raining in Hokkaido"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only 1 is a correct translation.

I can't speak to the Chinese sentence at all, but translation 2 sounds like a slightly unnatural translation of:

> 北海道では雪が降っていく。

Which means "In Hokkaido the snow will continue." (The ていく construction indicates that the action is occurring now and is expected to continue into the future.)

Note that the presence of the は particle gives the sentence a contrastive feel, like you've just said or are about to say that it's not snowing in Tōhoku, for example.